# Music discord js bot issue

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js

Does anyone know how I would go about resolving this error?

My Discord.JS music bot would just simply crashes when trying to play some old songs. The Discord.JS bot is currently being hosted on **herokuapp**.

```
19-03-12T15:08:08.576483+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/node_modules/ytdl-core-discord/node_modules/prism-media/src/core/FFmpeg.js:41
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576496+00:00 app[worker.1]:     this._readableState = this._reader._readableState;
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576499+00:00 app[worker.1]:                                        ^
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576501+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576502+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property '_readableState' of undefined
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576504+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at new FFmpeg (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core-discord/node_modules/prism-media/src/core/FFmpeg.js:41:40)
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576506+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ytdl.getInfo (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core-discord/index.js:23:24)
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576508+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at fn (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/info.js:365:9)
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576510+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at util.parallel (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/info.js:232:11)
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576511+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at checkDone (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/util.js:405:7)
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576513+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at SAXParser.parser.onend (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/info.js:288:26)
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576515+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at emit (/app/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:624:35)
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576517+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at end (/app/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:667:5)
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576519+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at SAXParser.write (/app/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:975:14)
2019-03-12T15:08:08.576520+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at SAXParser.close (/app/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:157:38)
```

Comment: Can you provide the related code so we can get a better understanding of where the problem occurs. I'd also be nice if you could reformat the error output in to a more readable format (e.g. an enter after each line)

Comment: I manage to resolve it with chmod permission settings. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is because your bot prefers recent music I think ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to resolve the error by setting chmod permission of root folder to 777.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct so it comes up as answered.